# Connection errors when connecting locally from VSC to Azure ML via MLflow tracking server

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, azure-machine-learning-service, mlflow

I'm experiencing problems when following the basic instructions from Azure ML docs to work locally on Python notebooks and track them in Azure ML via MLflow.

- I'm using a conda environment, it's activated and used as kernel in VSC.
- All modules from the docs are installed.
- I also have the config.json file in the same folder as the notebook.
- Azure ML standard workspace is selected in VSC (I think authentication is also okay, because i can see the whole menu tree from Azure ML in VSC)
- I'm on a Mac

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-use-mlflow-configure-tracking?view=azureml-api-2&tabs=cli%2Cmlflow

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-use-mlflow-cli-runs?view=azureml-api-2&tabs=interactive%2Ccli

When running the follow code:

```
from azure.ai.ml import MLClient
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential

ml_client = MLClient.from_config(credential=DefaultAzureCredential())
mlflow_tracking_uri = ml_client.workspaces.get(ml_client.workspace_name).mlflow_tracking_uri
```

I get this error:

*DefaultAzureCredential failed to retrieve a token from the included credentials.
Attempted credentials:
EnvironmentCredential: EnvironmentCredential authentication unavailable. Environment variables are not fully configured.
Visit https://aka.ms/azsdk/python/identity/environmentcredential/troubleshoot to troubleshoot.this issue.*

**Why is the standard code not working? I really have no clue what's wrong here. Does anybody experienced the same or knows how to solve this issue?**

Many thanks for the person(s) who can help me!:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after good research I have it working.

To help others with these problems, some things you might consider:

1. Make sure all modules are installed, in the above example I didn't load the `azure-core` module. But don't forget the `azure-ai-ml`.
2. The `DefaultAzureCredential` Class consist of multiple Classes for authentication. Mine was stuck at the `SharedToken` which gave a token but an expired one. So I created a `service principal` by registering an app and giving this app authorization for Azure ML. Thereafter I loaded these variable as environmental variables from a `.env` file.

I did some testing with the `EnvironmentalCredential` Class (part of the `DefaultAzureCredential`) and this gave me a token which I could use in the `DefaultAzureCredential`.

So main problems were:

- Not loading variable for authentication as environmental variables.
- Getting an expired token on the authentication method which I didn't want to use.

Answer (score 1):

Re. the `UnsupportedModelRegistryStoreURIException` exception: you can get this if you have not installed the `azureml-core` module. This module is not an explicit dependency of `azureml` or `azureml-mlflow`.

Comment: Hi Larry, I already did this and that worked! I’m still having troubles to receive the tracking URI via de SDK. I hope to receive the service principle soon to check if that works.

Answer (score 0):

If you see the error, you got the supported URI schemes are:
**['', 'file', 'databricks', 'databricks-uc', 'http', 'https', 'postgresql', 'mysql', 'sqlite', 'mssql']**.

As per [this](https://mlflow.org/docs/latest/python_api/mlflow.html#mlflow.set_tracking_uri) documentation you need to provide local path or empty string for locally tracking.

I have reproduced your issue, I got the same error.
Later, I executed the code by providing local path it executed
successfully.

```
import  mlflow
mlflow.set_tracking_uri("file://C:/Users/xxxx/xxxxx/ml/beerforecast/runs")
mlflow.set_experiment(experiment_name='experiment_with_mlflow')
```

And this is the output.

```
2023/05/09 12:35:01 INFO mlflow.tracking.fluent: Experiment with name 'experiment_with_mlflow' does not exist. Creating a new experiment.
<Experiment: artifact_location='[file://C:/xxxxx/xxxx/ml/beerforecast/runs/819102389238280179](file:///C:/xxxxx/xxxx/Desktop/ml/beerforecast/runs/819102389238280179)', creation_time=1683615901106, experiment_id='819102389238280179', last_update_time=1683615901106, lifecycle_stage='active', name='experiment_with_mlflow', tags={}>
```

Following is the files created under `runs` directory

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Did you notice that I am working on a tracking URI from Azure ML? I'm working locally, but not connecting to a local MLflow tracking server. I read that the `azureml://` prefix should work (even that it is not listed in the error message). So it should be a correct URI scheme. Or do you have to change this prefix to `https` or something?